# How to convert formatted string into Dictionary<string,string> format

Tags: c#, regex

**How to convert string to Dictionary Format for format provided below.**

```
var ss =  "[TTT, sdfsdf],[sfsdf, sdfsdf],[T44TT, sdfsdf]";
```

Comment: This is invalid C# and insufficient to make it clear what you are asking.  Explain what you are asking with valid C#.

Comment: Can you be more specific? what is the type of your variable ss? You can construct a dictionary<string, string> by using something like:
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>{{"TTT", "sdfsdf"}, {"sfsdf", "sdfsdf"}, {"T44TT", "sdfsdf"}};

Comment: "ss" is any object type . construct a dictionary<string, string> for the variable "ss".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code creates a `Dictionary<string,string>` where the key is the first string in each set of square brackets, and the value is the second string:

```
var ss =  "[TTT, sdfsdf],[sfsdf, sdfsdf],[T44TT, sdfsdf]";

var dict = ss.Split(new[] { "],", "[", "]" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .ToDictionary(i => i.Split(',')[0], i => i.Split(',')[1]);
```

The resulting dictionary has 3 entries:

```
Key: TTT    Value: sdfsdf
Key: sfsdf  Value: sdfsdf
Key: T44TT  Value: sdfsdf
```

It works by first splitting the initial string into an array of strings using `string.Split`.

The splitting happens every time a `"],"` or  `"["` or `"]"` is encountered.

This produces an array of strings like this:

```
TTT, sdfsdf
sfsdf, sdfsdf
T44TT, sdfsdf
```

This array then has the Linq extension method `ToDictionary` called on it. This allows you to specify a key and value generator method which can be run on each element in the array to create the keys and values.

The methods are:  `i => i.Split(',')[0]` (split the string by comma and grab the first bit)

and: `i => i.Split(',')[1]` (split the string by comma and grab the second  bit)

And there you have your `Dictionary`.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: Explanation added!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a collection of entities (I've used tuples), you can use `ToDictionary()` to project key and values for your dictionary:

```
var tuples = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
{
  new Tuple("TTT", "sdfsdf"), 
  new Tuple("sfsdf", "sfsdf")
};

var dictionary = tuples.ToDictionary(_ => _.Item1, _ => _.Item2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
var ss = "[TTT, sdfsdf],[sfsdf, sdfsdf],[T44TT, sdfsdf]";

var result =
    Regex.Matches(ss, @"\[([^,]*),\s*([^,]*)\]").Cast<Match>()
    .ToDictionary(m => m.Groups[1], m => m.Groups[2]);
```

Comment: what namespace needed to add for Cast?

Comment: Add `System.Linq` and `System.Text.RegularExpressions`.

Comment: please add the code of how to display them on console as well

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the following code.

```
var dictionary = ss.Substring(1, ss.Length - 2)
                   .Split(new string[] { "],[" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                   .Select(_ => _.Split(','))
                   .ToDictionary(parts => parts[0], parts => parts[1]);
```